# Pandas agg custom function with large number of keys

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

It is really slow when number of keys is above 10k, which is very common indeed. Is there any way to speed it up?

```
import pandas as pd

n = 10*1000000
ngroup = 10000
m = n//ngroup

d = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(n), "b":list(range(ngroup))*m})

%timeit dagg = d.groupby("b")["a"].agg(["mean","std"]).reset_index()
#700 ms

#custom function
%timeit dagg = d.groupby("b")["a"].agg(lambda x: x.mean()+x.std()).reset_index()
#4.37 s
```

A comparison in R's data.table

```
require(data.table)

n = 10*1000000
ngroup = 10000
m = n/ngroup
DT = data.table(a = 0:(n-1), b = rep(0:(ngroup-1), m))

system.time({dagg = DT[, .(m = mean(a), s = sd(a)), by = b]})
#0.42 sec

#custom function
f <- function(x)mean(x)+sd(x)
system.time({ dagg = DT[, .(k =f(a)), by = b] })
#0.81 sec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only achieve what you need (sum mean and std), I think doing out side the groupby is more efficient

```
%timeit d.groupby("b")["a"].agg(["mean","std"])
1 loop, best of 3: 698 ms per loop


%timeit d.groupby("b")["a"].agg(["mean","std"]).sum(1)
1 loop, best of 3: 704 ms per loop
```

Yours :

```
%timeit d.groupby("b")["a"].agg(lambda x: x.mean()+x.std())
1 loop, best of 3: 2.89 s per loop
```

Comment: Great answer.  You'll probably want to drop column "b" before calling `sum(1)` to match what the lambda is doing.

Comment: @PaSTE I think the b here is index :-) so we only adding up all column which is mean and std

Comment: @miradulo sorry ...I can not find it ...`d.groupby("b")["a"].agg(["mean","std"]).sum(1)`

Comment: Sure, IMO just didn't think that was the core of the question. But okay.

Comment: I want a general solution for all functions.

Comment: @user3226167 *I want a general solution for all functions*, it is hard give you one general solution here, But I will suggest doing the calculation out side the groupby, 1st it will save time , 2nd it will create less confusion

Comment: Actually I think your answer is general for all function constructed from addition or subtraction of vectorized functions.